# Django - forms.ChoiceField without using model

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to create a form to select an option without using a model for it. For some reason form is not showing up on the template. I tried below code, could someone help me with this?

form.py

```
class selectPostType(forms.Form):

    STATUS_CHOICES = (('1', 'Text Post'),('2', 'Image Post'),('3', 'Video Post'),)
    post_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
```

views.py

```
def selectPostType(request):
      form = selectPostType
      return render(request,'selectPostType.html',{'form':form})
```

html

```
<form action='.'  method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button class='btn btn-default' type='submit'>Select</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare the form and the view with the same name, try to change one of them. I think that is the problem.